# Como escrever e aparecer em algum lugar o que eu escrevi

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Bom, nos sites hoje em dia são encontrados algumas coisas que eu não sei explicar, por exemplo, pense em um formulário pedindo seu nome, você preenche, e na mesma hora aparece encima o seu nome, como se você estivesse digitando e aparecendo no formulário e encima. Como posso fazer isso?

Comment: Por favor, selecione a resposta que resolveu ou te ajudou a resolver o problema, escolher a melhor resposta ajuda as próximas pessoas que tenham a mesma dúvida.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Isso pode ser feito com javascript, manipulando o DOM a partir de eventos.
Neste exemplo, cada vez que o valor do input for alterado, o valor da div também será.

```js
  
 var alteraValor = function () {      
    document.getElementById('a').innerText = document.getElementById('b').value;        
}
```

```html
<input id="b" oninput="alteraValor()"/>    
 
<div id="a"></div>
```

Comment: Bom, eu queria que quando escrevesse aparecesse como div, tem como?

Comment: Sim, @Fkda só mudar o elemento a seu alterado e sua propriedade.

Answer (score 2):

Usando jQuery pode ser algo assim:

```
<div id="div_nome"></div>
<form>
    <input id="nome" value="" />
</form>

$("#nome").keyup(function() {
    $("#div_nome").text($(this).val());
});
```

Comment: Não apareceu nada. Poderia me ajudar?

Comment: Você incluiu o código `jquery`?

Answer (score 1):

Uma outra forma de se obter o resultado desejado:

```js
window.mostrarTexto= function(valor){
  var campo = document.getElementById("campo").value;
  div.innerHTML = campo; 
}
```

```html
<input id="campo" type="text" onkeyup="mostrarTexto(this.value)"/>
<div id="div" style="display:block"></div>
```

A diferença dessa forma com a apresentada pelo @AlexSander e basicamente o evento que chama a função

> `onkeyup` -> função é acionada quando o usuário solta uma tecla
>
> `oninput` -> função é acionada quando o elemento recebe uma entrada do usuário

Vale lembrar que `oninput` e um atributo adicionado no `HTML5` o que pode dificultar o seu uso em navegadores mais antigos...