# Como aparecer o que eu digitei no input em uma imagem

Tags: javascript, html

Olá, gostaria de saber como eu posso fazer o seguinte, eu tenho várias imagens com nomes, e criei um script em js para eu digitar no input e o que eu digitei aparecer embaixo, e dessa vez gostaria que formasse uma imagem.
Exemplo:
Eu escrevo o nome "andre".
Queria que o comando "img" (html), ficasse com o "src" para o link dessa imagem, por exemplo, eu já escreveria o diretório, e só viesse no nome "andre" no meio.

Ex:

Meu script com input:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.mostrarTexto= function(valor){
  var campo = document.getElementById("campo").value;
  div.innerHTML = campo; 
}
</script>
```

HTML:

```
<input id="campo" type="text" onkeyup="mostrarTexto(this.value)"/>
<div id="div" style="display:block"></div>
```

Comment: Não deu para entender muito a pergunta. Você quer renomear a imagem com o que é digitado? Ou chamar a imagem que for igual ao que é digitado?

Comment: Tipo, eu digito no input o nome "andre" e aparece no diretório da imagem como se o nome da imagem fosse andre. Se eu escrever "roberto" vai aparecer a imagem desse roberto. Deu pra entender?

Answer (score 2):

Seguindo mais ou menos a minha resposta na sua [outra pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/75595/14262)
Você pode utilizar o elemento `canvas` do `HTML5` para criar a imagem ao digitar.

```js
window.escreveNoCanvas = function(mensagem){
  var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
  var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
  
  //função criar a base branca do canvas
  context.fillStyle = "white";
  context.beginPath();
  context.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  context.fill();
  
  //aqui eu crio a mensagem
  context.font = '9pt Arial';
  context.fillStyle = 'black';
  context.fillText(mensagem, 0, canvas.height/2);

  //desenha tudo que foi escrito anteriormente no canvas
  context.stroke();
}
```

```html
<input type="text" onkeyup="escreveNoCanvas(this.value)">
<canvas id="myCanvas"></canvas>
```

---

### EDIT*

Se for somente alterar o `path` da imagem você pode fazer simplesmente assim:

```js
window.mudaImagem = function(mensagem){
  var imagem = document.getElementById('imagem');
  imagem.src = "https://www."+mensagem+".com.br/images/srpr/logo11w.png";
}
```

```html
Digite <b>"google"</b>: <input type="text" onkeyup="mudaImagem(this.value)"><br/><br/><br/>
<img id="imagem" src="##"/>
```

Comment: Eu entendi o que você fez, mas não é bem isso. Tipo, eu tenho uma imagem qualquer que o nome dela (em arquivo) é andre.png, e queria que após eu escrever o nome "andre" no input o img src funcionasse. E que tivesse um local para eu colocar o diretório, onde lá teriam o nome de todas os nomes que eu iria colocar no input.

Comment: Caso precise de um exemplo prático, posso editar minha pergunta.

Comment: @fkda editei a resposta, agora, o que você quer dizer com "um local para eu colocar o diretório, onde lá teriam o nome de todas os nomes que eu iria colocar"?

Comment: Eu consegui editar da forma que eu queria, a sua edição. Deu certinho, mas só falta uma coisinha, eu queria que quando a pessoa entrasse já aparecesse uma imagem, aí só se a pessoa mexer no input que mudaria, pra você entender mais, olha aí o que eu queria:

Comment: window.escreveNoCanvas = function(mensagem){
  var imagem = document.getElementById('imagem');
  imagem.src = "http://localhost:8090/howper/media/img/"+mensagem+".png";
}

Comment: no html: `<img id="imagem" src="##"/>` é só você definir o `src="caminhoDaImagemPadrão.jpg"`

Comment: Ah sim, muito obrigado. Resolvido.